Count distinct values across more than one column
I need to count distinct values that have been spread across more than one column. I have a method but suspect there is a more elegant way.
Example input:



year
project
staff 1
staff 2
staff 3
cost




2022
A

Ian

100


2023
A
Jim
Anne

200


2024
A
Anne
Jim
Peter
300


2023
B
Anne
Sue

400


2024
B


Dave
500



Expected output:



project
number_distinct_staff
total_cost




A
4
600


B
3
900



Current method:
SELECT project
    , COUNT(DISTINCT staff) AS num_distinct_staff
    , SUM(cost) AS total_cost
FROM (
    SELECT project, staff_1 AS staff, cost AS cost FROM table UNION ALL
    SELECT project, staff_2 AS staff, NULL AS cost FROM table UNION ALL
    SELECT project, staff_3 AS staff, NULL AS cost FROM table
) AS sub
GROUP BY project

This approach feels clumsy to me. I am worried that the asymmetric handling of columns (like cost in the example) makes the process vulnerable to double counting.
Is there a better way?

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example: (1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. (2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. (3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above. (4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

@YitzhakKhabinsky It's not very wise to copy-paste this comment on every question you see because obviously Simon did the most things you mention in your comment. If you really think you need to tell him what else you want, you should at least change your default comment to the current case.

@JonasMetzler, obviously ##1 and 4 are missing.  The list is not too long ##1 - 4.

Yeah it is a bit weird that you frequently post this comment, and then go right ahead and provide an answer :) if its missing a m-r-e you shouldn't be answering.

Your method looks perfectly fine to me; why do you think it is clumsy? There is no built- in (Standard SQL) method to deal with this situation (other than expecting the data to be modelled in a better way: the way your 'sub' subquery returns data - plus a primary key)

@tinazmu Note that the query in the question is invalid. I guess they meant ...SELECT project, staff_1 AS staff, cost FROM table... rather than ...SELECT project, staff_1, cost AS staff FROM table.... Then it will produce the correct result.

To be honest your design is denormalized. You should reall have a separate ProjectStaff table with multiple rows per project, then you wouldn't have such issues querying it.

@SimonSA did either of the answers solve your issue?

First off, your solution is correct you just had a little error,
see my dbFiddle
-- your solution after correction
SELECT project
    , COUNT(DISTINCT staff) AS num_distinct_staff
    , SUM(cost) AS total_cost
FROM (
    SELECT project, staff_1 as staff, cost FROM tbl UNION ALL
    SELECT project, staff_2, NULL AS staff FROM tbl UNION ALL
    SELECT project, staff_3, NULL AS staff FROM tbl
) AS sub
GROUP BY project

If you want to try something other than your solution or the other answer, another way is to use both string_agg and string_split like this
select t.project,
       count(distinct value) as number_distinct_staff,
       min(t.costs) as total_cost
from   ( select project,
                sum(cost) as costs,
                string_agg(staff_1, ',') + ',' + string_agg(staff_2, ',') + ',' + string_agg(staff_3, ',') as staffs
         from   tbl
         group by project
       )  t
  cross apply string_split(t.staffs, ',')
group by t.project

Here is the dbFiddle
And the result is



project
number_distinct_staff
total_cost




A
4
600


B
3
900




Please try the following solution leveraging a Table Value Constructor.
For the refence: The Table Value Constructor (aka the VALUES keyword)
Basically, we are converting columns to rows via VALUES (...)
db-fiddle
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (project CHAR(1), staff_1 VARCHAR(20), staff_2 VARCHAR(20), staff_3 VARCHAR(20), cost INT);
INSERT @tbl (project, staff_1, staff_2, staff_3, cost) VALUES
('A', NULL,  'Ian',  NULL, 100),
('A', 'Jim', 'Anne', NULL, 200),
('A', 'Anne', 'Jim', 'Peter', 300),
('B', 'Anne', 'Sue', NULL, 400),
('B', NULL,   NULL, 'Dave', 500);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t1.project
    , COUNT(DISTINCT staff) AS num_distinct_staff
    , SUM(t1.cost) AS total_cost
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (project, staff_1, cost),
    (project, staff_2, NULL),
    (project, staff_3, NULL)) AS t1(project, staff, cost)
GROUP BY t1.project;

Output



project
num_distinct_staff
total_cost




A
4
600


B
3
900




That's a clever way to do the job!

Great answer. t1.project seems unnecessary, you could use t.project
